# How to change color of background IconGenerator Android

Tags: android, marker

Im using Google Map Marker and IconGenerator, I can get marker and load data on marker, but I don't know how to change color of Icon Marker

This is my code:

```
IconGenerator tc = new IconGenerator(this);
    Bitmap bmp = tc.makeIcon("1000K"); // pass the text you want.
...
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp));
```

Default color of marker is white color, How to change color background of IconGenerator ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think if you want to pass text as a icon in google map then it's possible to using IconGenerator. I do following and it's work for me.

Create one style:

```
<style name="iconGenText">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```

Applying on Map:

```
IconGenerator icnGenerator = new IconGenerator(this);
icnGenerator.setTextAppearance(R.style.iconGenText);
```

Set Background :

```
IconGenerator icnGenerator = new IconGenerator(this);
icnGenerator.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_background));
```

but please use .9.png image for background.
you can generate .9.png file from [here](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html) and [here](http://inloop.github.io/shadow4android/)

Comment: for example, I set background is red color, .9.png will ok, isnt's it ?

Comment: yes, as i explain in my answer you can use whatever you want image or text.

Comment: Hi @Shailesh Limbadiya: how to generate .9.png in your link? I don't know select which file

Comment: whatever you want and i add another link to generate .9.png image.Please see my answer

Comment: @ThanhNamPham, Its my pleasure. Please give up vote so other can get help.